# Is android (AVD) command still supported?

Tags: android, command-line, android-virtual-device

my question is about the recommended method to create and manage AVDs.

I'd like to use the command line (commands such as "android avd", "android create avd"...) because I have a weak computer with 3GB of RAM. So running Android Studio with GUI at the same time as other stuff is sadly not always an option.

But the "android" command seems obsolete according to: [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html?hl=ca), in favor of the Android Studio GUI.

Can anyone confirm this? Is the "android" command not maintained anymore?
In which case, why is it still available in the latest version of the SDK and Android Studio?

Thank you in advance.